# Generic method with generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics, generic-method

I want to create generic method with generic parameter like that:

```
public class BaseResponse<T>
{
    public ResponseReturnCode Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class LoginResponse : BaseResponse<LoginData>
```

```
 private async Task<T> CreateResponse<T,U>(HttpResponseMessage responseMessage) where T : BaseResponse<U>
        {    
            var responseBody = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
               
            var responseDto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseBody);
            // Some additional stuff here but I am not need U type for that.
            // I am only touching not generic part of BaseResponse here.
            //...
            return responseDto;
        }
```

This is working:

```
var responseDto = await CreateResponse<LoginResponse, LoginData>(responseMessage);
```

```
private async Task<T> CreateResponse<T,U>(HttpResponseMessage responseMessage) where T : BaseResponse<U> {...}
```

**I don't want to specify internal type "LoginData" when calling this method.**
But this statment dosn't work:

```
var responseDto = await CreateResponse<LoginResponse>(responseMessage);
private async Task<T> CreateResponse<T>(HttpResponseMessage responseMessage) where T : BaseResponse<U> where U : class
{...}
```

"U" type i unknown...

this also doesn't work:

```
var responseDto = await CreateResponse<LoginResponse>(responseMessage);
```

```
private async Task<T> CreateResponse<T>(HttpResponseMessage responseMessage) where T : BaseResponse<object>
{...}
```

In Java i can use wildcard but hot to solve this i c#?

Comment: Is this an option? `private async Task<T> CreateResponse<T>(HttpResponseMessage responseMessage) where T : BaseResponse<LoginData>`?

Comment: Are you going to use `U` in the method? If not, something similar to wildcards could be done depending on what parts of `BaseResponse` your method depends on. Can you show the methods/properties of `BaseResponse` that `CreateResponse` depend on?

Comment: No. I will not be using U type. I just want check in CreateResponse that parmeter is BaseResponse<>.

Comment: ```BaseResponse<LoginData>``` is not an option.Responses will be different but always based on BaseResponse<class>. I have updated my initial post with more code.